# How can i make a texture/material of this kind of fabric that looks realistic?

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, uv, node-editor

I'd like to have a material or texture that looks like a patchwork fabric kind of like these images here, with checkered decorations, do you have any advice/nodes to make it look at least semi realistic? It doesn't need to have such elaborate decorations but ti should still look similar

[image: Image of a round couch pillow with patch work decoration on it]

[image: Image of a couch pillow with patch work decoration on it]

Comment: Hi :). What have you tried so far and where *exactly* are you stuck? Such material has multiple tricky aspects.

Comment: You might want to check out [Knittr - Procedural Knitwear Shader](https://simonthommes.gumroad.com/l/Knittr) by Simon Thommes